# VBA IE selecting Radio Button

Tags: vba, vbscript

I am trying to click on a Customer Name or Customer Number radio buttons on the web using VBA, but am not having much luck. I am getting an error "Object variable or With block variable not set". Any help greatly appreciated!
My code is as follows:

```
Set HTMLdoc = IE.Document

With IE.Document
    .getElementsByName("mainTabView:searchtype").Item(0).Checked = True
End With
```

Here is the HTML source codes where the Customer Number and Customer name radio buttons are:

```html
<div class="radioButtonContainer">
   <div class="ui-radiobutton ui-widget" id="mainTabView:customerNumberOption">
       <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
          <input name="mainTabView:searchType" tabindex="-110" id="mainTabView:searchType:0" type="radio" checked="checked"            

value="false"></input>
   </div>
<div class="ui-radiobutton-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-state-active">
    <span class="ui-radiobutton-icon ui-icon ui-icon-bullet"></span>
 </div>
</div>
<label class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget" id="mainTabView:j_id1942712369_6a329e5d" for="mainTabView:customerNumberOption">Number</label>
<div class="ui-radiobutton ui-widget" id="mainTabView:customerNameOption">
  <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
     <input name="mainTabView:searchType" tabindex="-110" id="mainTabView:searchType:1" type="radio" value="true">
  </div>
<div class="ui-radiobutton-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
    <span class="ui-radiobutton-icon"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<label class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget" id="mainTabView:j_id1942712369_6a329db2" for="mainTabView:customerNameOption">Name</label>
 
  

   <div style="width: 40px; height: 1px;"></div>
<div class="ui-chkbox ui-widget" id="mainTabView:includePublicCheckbox">
  <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
     <input name="mainTabView:includePublicCheckbox_input" tabindex="-120" id="mainTabView:includePublicCheckbox_input" type="checkbox">
  </div>
<div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
   <span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-c"></span>
 </div>
</div><label class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget" id="mainTabView:j_id1942712369_6a329df5" for="mainTabView:includePublicCheckbox_input">Include Open 

Tariffs</label>
</div>​
```

Comment: note: this does not fix your problem, just corrects an inconsistency in your code .... you define a variable `Set HTMLdoc = IE.Document` and then you do not use it `with ie.document`  .... get rid of the `with` command and use `HTMLdoc.getElementsByName( ....`

Comment: how many elements does `HTMLdoc.getElementsByName("mainTabView:searchtype")`  return?

Comment: Try this `IE.document.getElementByID("mainTabView:searchType:0").Click`?

Comment: Hi jsotola, I tried  HTMLdoc.getElementsByName("mainTabView:searchtype").Item(0).Checked = True. I am getting an error Object Variable or with block not set.

Comment: Hi Ryan, IE.document.getElementByID("mainTabView:searchType:0").Click‌​ returns error "Object variable or with block not set"

Comment: Thank you all for the tips.  I finally got it to work with these codes: IE.Document.GetElementById("mainTabView:j_id1942712369_6a329e5d").Click
    IE.Document.GetElementById("mainTabView:j_id1942712369_6a329db2").Click
    IE.Document.GetElementById("mainTabView:j_id1942712369_6a329df5").Click